# The node_modules folder from my react app is not getting deleted, how do I delete it from my system?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app

I created a `react app` using the `create-react-app` command and after I was done with it, I wanted to delete the app. I tried deleting the whole folder and it deleted everything except a few particular files in the `node_modules` folder.

I'm getting the following message when I'm trying to delete.

[image]

Comment: ```rm -rf node_modules``` to delete node modules or  ```rm -rf react_app_name``` to delete your app - but be careful as this is irreversible. Also, take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @sintribu thanks, it worked! and yes I will, I am new to asking questions on stack overflow haha

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to move the folder inside another folder and delete the parent folder.
2. Move the folder to a different location and then delete it.
3. Restart the pc and then delete the folder.

This methods works sometimes in windows.

Answer (score 0):

`rm -rf <what you want to delete>` in terminal works all the time.